# eclipse graphical layout not showing anything

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, layout

I am doing a mobile application on Eclipse and once I re-installed my Android SDK after installation something odd happens when I make an XML and try to view it, via graphical layout it does not show anything and it's hard to make something you can't see. Here is a print screen of what im saying. What seems to be the problem if the XML is not showing anything? This is the first time I encountered this and I didn't get results from searching the net. I tried restarting right clicking but nothing happened, saw this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454258/android-graphical-layout-not-working-doesnt-show-anything)and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848385/graphical-layout-not-working-in-eclipse-with-adt-10-1) but it's not the same as my problem[image][image][image]

Comment: Maybe your Android SDK and ADT don't have the same, exact versions. Or, you tried to run Android with JDK v7 instead of v6.

Comment: @ChuongPham do you mind if i ask how to determine the version of jdk and how to match it on sdk and adt and

Comment: How is behaving Eclipse in overall besides this? is it slow?

Comment: To see what JDK version you're using, select **Windows | Preferences | Java | Installed JREs**. To see what Android SDK and ADT versions you're using, select **Help | About Eclipse** and click the **Android Open Source Project icon*. In summary, you'll need something like Android SDK v22.6.2, ADT v22.6.2 and JDK 1.6.45.

Comment: @ChuongPham please check update i will add images

Comment: @LuisLavieri all is ok the only problem is i cant see the graphical layout in xml. so i cant tell if the layout is ok now or needs adustment

Comment: Is this happening for just one file or all layout files? Try closing you rproject and opening  different one and then seeing the graphical layout in that one.

Comment: @SidJagannathan all xml are not showing graphical representation.

Comment: Ah OKjust wanted to rule  out a project specific or file specific problem. Looks like you may have uninstall ADT and reinstall it making sure you have the right version for your SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i found it. Repository? im updating a lot of repository now hoping to fix the problem

Comment: Did it work?  I'm having the exact same problem.  I updated all of my SDK packages.  I have SDK 22.6.2 and ADT 2.3.3.

Comment: After going through a number of cycles of installing with the ADT I eventually got things to settle down as far as the versions agreeing.  As for the layout, I still seem to have the problem.  After fiddling around, I can usually get the layout, but I wish I could remember what I'm doing.  If I catch it next time, I'll come back and post.

Answer (score 1):

This Question was asked 1 year ago, I am sure that you have get your solution, however I was also facing the same problem but got the solution in eclipse, here it is:

1. Goto help->AboutEclipse->Installation details.
2. check the version of Android DDMS, Android development tool, Android hierarchy viewer, Android native development tool, Android trace view and tracer for openGl ES in installed software tab.
3. If they have different version than you have to update all of them.
4. Goto help->check for update in eclipse and follow the instruction.
5. Then restart eclipse.

This solved my problem. There is no need to change jdk version or your minimum sdk version of your app.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  As you can see from the screen shots all tools are at the same version and the update manager indicates there are not any updates available.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like eclipse is reading all files associated with sdk and that takes some time... Especially if you have lots of stuff in your .xml view

Maybe you just need to wait for some time for eclipse to do his job

Comment: i waited for like hours but nothing is happening.it doesnt display anything

Comment: did you cross checked adt plugin version?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried clicking on the layout and doing the following?

Open With --> Android Layout Editor or Legacy Android Layout Editor

Comment: Choose other option open with anyone then choose again open with android layout editor, that works for me one time

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the manifest minimum sdk is not support to view the layout.to resolve that change the api level. also you can try using `OpenWith ->Layout Editor` on the xml file which u want to open from project explorer under res folder.

Comment: update adt plugin, guess it will help or u would need to reinstall adt bundle

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem but what i did was changing the option from android 22:android (M) preview to android 22:android 5.1.1 and that you can change by going in drop down menu for android version to use when rendering layouts in eclipse : above zoom in and zoom out button.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top right corner with a little android icon and in the drop down menu, select a particular Android a.b

As soon as you click on the API Level, (Example API 22) you will have your graphical layout :)
Then you can drag and drop too :D :)

I was also facing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks again but as I posted I tried that without any luck.