# Eclipse Android Plugin Graphical Layout Not Showing Anything

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-plugin

I'm using the ADT plugin and have a problem that the layout doesn't show anything; I can't drag and drop and the manual add to the XML doesn't display a thing.

The message "This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in" is displayed at the bottom of the graphical layout window.

I have Android SDK API 25 and 23 installed; all updates applied; eclipse Neon 2. JDK 8 installed and 1.6 compliance selected for project.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the ADT plugin. The plugin shows V 23.0.7 and I tried selecting that in the layout window (also tried V25).

I also followed this post to no avail [Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800341/eclipse-graphical-layout-not-showing-anything/41837483#41837483http://)

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Android Studio is the official IDE for Android. ADT 23.0.7 is the last updated build tools. [Are you aware of this](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)? Also, try changing your Android SDK API from 25 to 23.

Comment: I was not aware of that.  Changing the SDK to 23 didn't help but thats a moot point now.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thank you for informing me.